Error parsing '/home/kento/ws/src/my_robot_luanch/package.xml':
I was trying to build a python launch file and I got this error
Starting >>> my_robot_luanch
--- stderr: my_robot_luanch                         
Error parsing '/home/kento/ws/src/my_robot_luanch/package.xml':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 610, in parse_package_string
    root = dom.parseString(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 2000, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 922, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 220, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 21, column 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 150, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/ros/jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 53, in main
    raise e
  File "/opt/ros/jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 49, in main
    package = parse_package_string(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 612, in parse_package_string
    raise InvalidPackage('The manifest contains invalid XML:\n%s' % ex, filename)
catkin_pkg.package.InvalidPackage: Error(s) in package '/home/kento/ws/src/my_robot_luanch/package.xml':
The manifest contains invalid XML:
mismatched tag: line 21, column 2
CMake Error at /opt/ros/jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:95 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  /opt/ros/jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py
  /home/kento/ws/src/my_robot_luanch/package.xml
  /home/kento/ws/build/my_robot_luanch/ament_cmake_core/package.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:49 (_ament_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/jazzy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package.cmake:63 (ament_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (ament_package)


---
Failed   <<< my_robot_luanch [6.82s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [7.32s]
  1 package failed: my_robot_luanch
  1 package had stderr output: my_robot_luanch


We should really see your launch file. Please [edit] and add it, and use code formatting (\``...````)

In the error log, it says that you have mismatched tag. You probably forgot to close one of the tags or forgot to add \ to the closing tags.
For example:
<launch> <launch>

is wrong. It must be
<launch> </launch>


Without seeing your file it it difficult to know exactly what the issue is.
However, as an extension to Alp Sarica's answer, you have spelt launch incorrectly, in my_robot_luanch, by transposing the u and a. Therefore, it is possible that you have mismatched tags due to a spelling issue, as opposed to having omitted the closing tag.
For example
<launch> </luanch>

will also result in the same error occurring.
The line should, obviously, be
<launch> </launch>

I would suggest checking the spelling of your tags carefully.
